# Flexbox - align-self: flex-end horizontally

Tags: css, flexbox

How to align `div.c` to the right end with flexbox like below?

```
+--------------+
|A  B        C |
+--------------+
```

The rule `align-self: flex-end;` seems to align the box to the bottom even though `flex-direction: row;`

```
+--------------+
|A  B          |
|      C       |
+--------------+
```

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
}

.a {
  background-color: red;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.b {
  background-color: cyan;
  align-self: flex-start
}

.c {
  background-color: green;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box a">
  </div>
  <div class="box b">
  </div>
  <div class="box c">
  </div>
</div>
```

See the fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/rootnode/m5hyxLhb/7/

Comment: updated link https://jsfiddle.net/Lv9v9r3v/1/

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`align-self: flex-end;` only goes "column", in your case you have two options:

1. `justify-content: space-between;` on `.container`, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5hyxLhb/5/)
2. remove the `align-self` on both elements and use `margin-left: auto;` on `.b`, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5hyxLhb/3/)
3. 

```
.container {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
}

.a {
  background-color: red;
}

.b {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

2. 

```
.container {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; 
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
}

.a {
  background-color: red;
}

.b {
  background-color: cyan;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

**EDIT** 
now that you edited your question to be 3 boxes you can have a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5hyxLhb/8/),

```
.a {
  background-color: red;
}

.b {
  background-color: cyan;
}

.c {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: had to edit my question, so that there're 3 elements instead of 2. So that 1 of those goes to the right and rest remains left. Cannot use justify-content in that case.

Comment: you can use my option 2 @RootNode

Comment: margin-left: auto seems to be working, awesome. however, i would have thought that there had been flexbox rule for this. So that align-self: flex-end would obey the flex direction. I guess this is the way to do this.

Comment: @RootNode yea I get the confusion regarding the flex-end, you can read the awesome guide for flexbox over att css-tricks https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 11):

**Updated answer**

As per new question, align a single item to the right by adding `margin-left: auto;` to that item.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4nrLwzdx/)

**Original answer** 
Use the `justify-content` property on your container.

```
.container {
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

A good resource for flex properties [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3vt2ton/)

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
}
.a {
  background-color: red;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.b {
  background-color: cyan;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box a">
  </div>
  <div class="box b">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: had to edit my question, so that there're 3 elements instead of 2. So that 1 of those goes to the right and rest remains left. Cannot use justify-content in that case.

Comment: The problem with space-between is that you are not safe if elements are not shown in any state.

Answer (score 1):

If you have flex-direction:'row'  and want to make an item horizontally at the end, just use `margin-left:'auto'`  it will work accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
+--------------+
|A  B        C |
+--------------+
```

I put a new element G into it.

```
+--------------+
|A  B   G    C |
+--------------+
```

set the G flex-grow: 1, all of the other code is the same.

```
.g {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

it works for me